# Add children view controller in a controller that pushed in a navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, containers

I had a simple view controller called ViewController, it is in a navigation stack, the structure is like following:

```
UINavigationControlelr
  UIViewController
    ViewController
```

The ViewController had a children view controller called a, I add a to ViewController, a's frame is ViewController's bounds. I have two another UIViewController called b and c, I add b and c to a. b's frame is

```
CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
```

c's frame is

```
CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
```

If I set the navigation bar translucent to true, the view shows right, like below:
[image]

But when I set the navigation bar translucent to false, something weird happened.
[image]

What's going on. How to fix that problem?
The project is simple, you can also download from here to test the problem: [download](https://github.com/leizh007/HiPDA)

Comment: if you haven't already tried it, view debugger might be able to help.

Comment: your view height is being set to 36, exactly 64 pixels less than the height you set, I'd say it has something to do with the insets.

Comment: yep, it is being called too early, and by the time iOS adjusts view's frame to avoid the non-translucent black bar (i.e. adds 64 pixels to view's origin.y), your child view frames have already been set. answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <strike>problem</strike> cause is by default `UIViewController`'s `view` has `FlexibleWidth` &
`FlexibleHeight`

`bController` and `cController`'s `view` has extra gap 64 pixel (navBar(44) + status bar(20)). Now when you resize it has those 'FlexibleWidth`&`FlexibleHeight` to play with.

Solution could be making `autoresizingMask` to `.None`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    bController = b()
    cController = c()

    bController.view.autoresizingMask = .None
    cController.view.autoresizingMask = .None

    displayContentController(bController, toFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    displayContentController(cController, toFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
}
```

Comment: actually, the real issue is that `viewDidLoad` is not the right place to do view layout. Also, we should really stop using autoresizingMasks to shoe horn layout now that we have come so far with autolayout.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting view frames in `viewDidLoad`, please note that view layout is not done until much later. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, respectively, are called before and after the layout occurs).

Move your frame setting code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and it will work fine.

**NOTE:**: You could also get away with setting the view's frame in `viewWillAppear` but that's the the right place to set frames. `viewWillAppear` is called just before view is about to appear, view layout can change after the view has appeared (e.g. in response to device rotation).

Comment: Thank you, I set views frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews, it works. But in viewWillAppear, it does not work. I set views frame in viewDidAppear, it works.

Comment: I did not recommend using `viewWillAppear`, If you read my answer, it seems to be discouraging it because, even though it could some times work, it doesn't always work.